# Password validation using rest web-services in android

Tags: android, rest, web-services

Here i am facing a problem with password validation which is when i entering correct password but it is saying the password is incorrect. Here i am using rest web services below is my code please help me.

```
 EditText password;
   String Passwordstr;
   Button btn_go;    
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);  
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passET);    
    btn_go = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_go);    
    btn_go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Passwordstr = password.getText().toString();
            if (Passwordstr.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Please, Enter Your Password.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

                new MyAsyncTask().execute(Passwordstr);
            }
        }
    });

}    
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {    
        String res = PostData(params);    
        return res;
    }

    public String PostData(String[] args) {
        String s = "";

        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:82/demo/login.php");

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            s = readResponse(httpResponse);

        } catch (Exception exception) {
        }

        return s;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if (result.equals("true")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Main3Activity.class);
          intent.putExtra("Password", Passwordstr);                               
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }

    public String readResponse(HttpResponse res) {
        InputStream is = null;
        String return_text = "";

        try {
            is = res.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line = "";
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            return_text = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return return_text;
    }
}
}
```

I am developing an  android app in this my aim is to connect to a web page through web-server, here i am using Rest call and java code.Please help me any one.

Comment: who is saying wrong password?your  REST API ?

Answer (score 0):

In your post execute you have to check the null value not the true value like this

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if (result!=null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Main3Activity.class);
          intent.putExtra("Password", Passwordstr);
            //No Full Name
            //MyHomeActivity.putExtra("GetDisplayName",user.getDisplayName());
            //  MyHomeActivity.putExtra("GetPhotoUrl",user.getPhotoUrl());
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Hide the progress bar
            //  progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this but, It is redirecting to another activity even when i gave wrong password also how to control it

Comment: You have to check the return value from the doInBackground()

Comment: The returing value is pass to the postexecute() method from that

Comment: You have to validate the password

Comment: can u please explain clearly because i am new to android.

Comment: When you execute the doInBackground method then he return the result of that method

Comment: So you return the result in S variable

Comment: s = readResponse(httpResponse);  this value is pass to the next method that is postexecute(String s) s variable contain the response from server .So your response contain value that means your password is correct otherwise incorrect

Answer (score 0):

try this as you are not create post parameters pair with key and value.

List nameValuePair = new ArrayList(1);
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "password"));

httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

Also hit rest api from postman or hurl.it with same password and check the response.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [android-async-http](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) simple , fast

and u can access UI thread an Views on respond methods

```
 RestClient.get("statuses/public_timeline.json", null, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
            // If the response is JSONObject instead of expected JSONArray
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray timeline) {
            // Pull out the first event on the public timeline
            JSONObject firstEvent = timeline.get(0);
            String Text = firstEvent.getString("text");
             textview.setText(Text);

            // Do something with the response
            System.out.println(tweetText);
        }
    });
```